# Create a custom border style based on an image through CSS

Tags: css, wordpress-theming

I'm creating [a website using Wordpress](https://thestudycubes.leanbrewery.com/) and would like to change some of the styles. One challenge I faced is to create a border for my recent blog posts to look like the one as attached. This is the [image of the expected outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZXfZ.png)

I have the [SVG image file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qNYX1CApNbfEN0Ldzi4yJpgh4ZUDMC0p) from my designer. Taking into consideration of scalability, I do not plan to use the image as the background. I heard a way of using the left side as the border and background-repeat it.

I'm relatively new in this and would appreciate if any guru can guide me how to do this. Any alternative method is also fine.

Thanks a million!

Comment: why do not use `background-image`??

Comment: or do you wnat to create this border by css as image??

Comment: You should not include 'thank' in posts. See this meta post: [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950)

Answer (score 0):

I realize you wanted to use the border CSS approach but I think it would be hard to do without distorting the image if your content changes at all. 
After thinking it over and trying a few things I think the best approach would be to use a pseudo element with a repeating background image to create that left border effect. I think this would be the most flexible and responsive route to take.

I threw together a [CodePen demo](https://codepen.io/mcurren/pen/PBEegX/) with heavily annotated CSS since I was not sure of your familiarity with CSS in general. Look at the CodePen link for more details but this is the general gist of it:

**HTML**

```
<div class="book"> Your content goes here... </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.book {
  border: 2px solid #F3A333;
  position: relative;
}

.book:before { 
  content: ''; 
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/8X3apmL.png);
  background-size: 100% auto;
  width: 18px;
  transform: translateX(-55%);
}
```

Hope that helps. Feel free to use this code and the SVG I made for it (shown in CodePen) as you'd like.

Comment: I managed to achieve what I need using the border-image css. That allows me the scalability of the image size.